# how to read a file to data frame and print some colums in R

Tags: r, printing

I got a question about reading a file into data frame using R.
I don't understand "getwd" and "setwd", do we must do these before reading the files?

and also i need to print some of the columns in the data frame, and only need to print 1 to 30,how to do this?

Kinds regards

Comment: Was is a "data frame" here? What environment are you working in? What language / shell do you use as a base?

Comment: using R, i got an excel file and try to read it in R

Comment: Then please add some tags to your question accordingly. And mention those details. How else do you expect people to understand your question?

Comment: You have two questions here. I've answered the first one. You should probably post your second question as a new question and provide additional details about precisely what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getwd` tells you what your current working directory is. `setwd` is used to change your working directory to a specified path. [See the relevant documentation here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html) or by typing `? getwd` or `? setwd` in your R console.

Using these allows you to shorten what you type into, e.g., `read.csv` by just specifying a filename without specifying its full path, like:

```
setwd('C:/Users/Me/Documents')
read.csv('myfile.csv')
```

instead of:

```
read.csv('C:/Users/Me/Documents/myfile.csv')
```